# What's the best way to store post_meta value in variable, with a default value?

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

What's the most efficient and simplest way to store a post_meta value in a variable, along with a default value if the meta_key doesn't exist?

I want to use something like this, the meta_value will always be a number:

```
$bv_faq_thumbs_up = isset(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true)) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true) : 0;
```

But this throws a PHP error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think of something like:

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true) === null) {
    $bv_faq_thumbs_up = 0;
} else {
    $bv_faq_thumbs_up = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true);
}
```

But that seems quite long-winded and bloated, is this the correct way (in terms of speed and efficiency, and tidiness)

Comment: `metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up' );` should return a Bool for you

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/

Comment: @Stender Thanks, I think I'm going to go with this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Stender's comment, I found using `metadata_exists` instead of `isset` allows the same idea to work, still contained within a single sentence, and only using the `get_post_meta()` function once, whilst setting a default value.

```
$bv_faq_thumbs_up = metadata_exists('post', $post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up') ? get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true) : 0;
```

Comment: Glad you made it work - I am an idiot for not making it into an answer though :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try this code;

```
$bv_faq_thumbs_up = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true);

if(empty($bv_faq_thumbs_up)) {
    $bv_faq_thumbs_up = 0;
}
```

OR

```
$bv_faq_thumbs_up = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true);

$bv_faq_thumbs_up = (!empty($bv_faq_thumbs_up)) ? $bv_faq_thumbs_up : 0;
```

OR

```
if(metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up' ) === null) {
    $bv_faq_thumbs_up = 0;
} else {
    $bv_faq_thumbs_up = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_bv_faq_thumbs_up', true);
}
```

*for future users*

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, however I like the idea that Stender gave in the comments if that's alright.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this since PHP 7:

```
$result = get_post_meta($id, $key, true) ?? false; // false is default value
```

Alternative:

```
if (($result = get_post_meta($id, $key, true) ?? false) !== false) {
    // do stuff but only if the $key exists
    echo $result;
}
```

There is no need to call metadata_exists() or get_post_meta() twice. Explanation for ?? can be found here https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-null-coalescing-operator/